# Expectation of a composite indicator function

Tags: random-variables, expectation, binary

I did not find any reference over the stack community and internet, but hopefully you might help me. I am trying to compute the expectation (over time $t$) of the following (composite) indicator function:

$\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1}\{u_{t} \leq \mathbb{1}\{X_{t} \geq x\}k\}\right]$,

where $u_{t}$ are independent random draws from from a $U[0,1]$ in every period $t$, $\mathbb{1}\{X_{t} \geq x\}$ is a standard indicator function that returns $1$ if the condition inside the curly bracket is true and $0$ otherwise, and $k$ is a constant.

I am wondering if the expression above is equivalent to the one below

$\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1}\{u_{t} \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1}\{X_{t} \geq x\}\right]k\}\right]$.

If it is, I can carry forward the whole calculation. I just need to show this first step.

Any suggestion is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions are equal (not sure if I'd call them "equivalent") if $k\le1$. If $k\gt1$, the second expression will generally be greater, since taking the expectation will tend to avoid the clipping.

In detail: Let $k\in[0,1]$, and $p_1=\mathbb P(X_t\ge x)$ and $p_0=\mathbb P(X_t\lt x)$; then

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1}\{u_{t} \leq \mathbb{1}\{X_{t} \geq x\}k\}\right]=p_0\mathbb1\{u_t\le0\}+p_1\mathbb1\{u_t\le k\}=p_1k
$$

and

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1}\{u_{t} \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1}\{X_{t} \geq x\}\right]k\}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1}\{u_{t} \leq p_0\cdot0+p_1k\}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1}\{u_{t} \leq p_1k\}\right]=p_1k\;.
$$

Comment: Thx @joriki, indeed $k \in (0,1)$. Could you expand a little bit your intuition? I am not sure what you mean by "clipping". (I also have the same intuition as of now)

Comment: @MarcosRFernandes: I've added the details.

Comment: thx @joriki. It is clear now!

Comment: @MarcosRFernandes: By "clipping", I mean the effect that in $\mathbb E[\mathbb 1\{u_t\le c\}]=\max (0,\min(1,c))$ the $c$ is "clipped" to $1$ if it exceeds $1$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help @joriki! I am building reputation here and as soon as I can upvote your answer, I will do that. For now I can only select it as the best answer. Cheers!